# Divide table data into manageable chunks

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Consider a table in Oracle 11g that has `81.000` rows:

```
create  table myTable 
    (
      key1 number not null,
      key2 number not null, 
      key3 number not null,
      col1 varchar2(100),
      col2 varchar2(100),
      col3 varchar2(100)
    );
```

the combination `key1, key2, key3` is the primary key of the table.

I would like to divide table data into chunks of `10.000` rows and give each chunk to a  `dbms_job.submit` to execute some operations on these rows concurrently.

Important thing here is not to miss any of the records - all records must be processed. Also, bear in mind that keys value are not sequential at all.

One way that I thought of was to create a temporary table

```
create table mytemp as (select rownum, mytable.* from myTable)
```

and then work with sequential rownumbers ... 
something like this:

```
for i in 0..(maxChunkNumber-1) loop 
    dbms_job.submit( 'process(i*10000+1,(i+1)*10000)');
end loop;
```

however adding  `rownum` to the select above increases drastically the time needed for temporary table creation.

Is there any better way to achieve that?

Your input is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: You're on 11g. Is there any reason why you don't want to use [DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_parallel_execute_11gR2)?

Comment: Add temporary integer counter  column, after that - process table with this counter.

Comment: @fen1x could you elaborate on that "integer counter column" ?

Comment: @APC  probably your right - I guess it'll do the breaking into chunks for me ... worth an attempt (to be honest i was considering checking out parallel execute at some point ...  but then somehow sidetracked  and went for dbms_job.submit ;-)

Comment: @Plirkee 1) `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN COUNTER INTEGER` 2) Use `FOR` cycle to fill it with integers from 1 to 81000. 3) Use `COUNTER` column in your script instead of `rownum`.

Comment: @all please do not post answers as comments but post them as answers.

Comment: 1. Absolutely DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE. 2. Ordering by PK and then getting ROW_NUMBER over partition. 3. DO NOT alter the table, in order to introduce a counter, please ..

Answer (score 1):

Use ORA_HASH and split the records into 8 buckets. Process each bucket with DBMS_JOB or DBMS_SCHEDULER.

```
select * from myTable 
where ora_hash(key1 + key2 + key3, 8) = 1; -- bucket 1

select * from myTable 
where ora_hash(key1 + key2 + key3, 8) = 2; -- bucket 2
```

Comment: Interesting approach. But is it **guaranteed** that these buckets are not overlapping?

Comment: @Plirkee: Short answer, yes.

Comment: How about a little bit longer one?  ;-)  I mean can you provide any hints - as why there would be no overlapping?

Comment: @Plirkee: In this article is mentioned that ORA_HASH is used in hash partitioning: https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2009/11/21/ora_hash-function/

Comment: Actually my bad, buckets are obviously not overlapping - the only thing I could worry about is the even distribution of rows into the buckets. I am up- voting this..

Comment: @Plirkee hash is always hash it is almost unique but not guaranteed unique https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9531842700346956612

Comment: @jareeq I did the same mistake ... The thing is that in this particular case we don't care about uniqueness actually its most certainly non unique (only 8 possible outcomes!). But it is a function - so same input always gives the same output - thus specific key always ends up in the same 'bucket'.  Now I don't know how **evenly distributed** will be the keys in the buckets - unfortunately I haven't found the time to research that part yet..

Comment: @Plirkee that's right - look at my answer above about Steward Ashton method. It deal with distribution looking to extends and generating ranges of rowids. We are using it to divide replication of data to dbms_parallel processing. You don't even care about key everything is about rowid.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use dbms_parallel_execute.
Second go to more intelligent and faster design proposed in excellent example from Steward Ashton:

[Splitting a Table into Rowid Ranges of Equal Size](https://stewashton.wordpress.com/2015/07/01/splitting-a-table-into-rowid-ranges-of-equal-size/)

From unusual things you need access to dba_extents, but that will by low price for nice solution. The key thing is that key no matter any more because you use rowid.